# Can Lvalue Reference be bounded to Rvalue Reference? What will happen during the process?

Tags: c++, reference, type-conversion, rvalue-reference

I am trying to figure out the meaning of the following snippet:

```
int main() {
    int&& a = 2;
    int& b = a;     // (*)
}
```

I know `a` is an lvalue expression of type "rvalue reference to **int**", and `b` is a general variable with type "lvalue reference to **int**". However, the initialization `(*)` of `b` seems weird. Since the type of `a` is not an **int**, it cannot match the type that `b` refers to. Can anyone explain this result? Is there any implicit conversion happening during the initialization `(*)`? Or is there any concept or keyword that I missed?

The code can be compiled and run successfully in [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nqEdY5Yf6).

Answer (score 1):

Any reference acts as if it's the referred object. Thus when you bind a reference `b` to another reference `a`, you actually bind it to the object `a` refers to.

One tricky part is that rvalue reference is an lvalue itself and C++ allows you to bind only lvalue reference to lvalues, thus you won't be able to bind another rvalue reference here:

```cpp
int&& a = 2;
int&& b = a; // error
```

Another notable side-effect, is that `a` in your sample extends the lifetime of the temporary to the end of the given scope (to be precise to the end of `a` reference lifetime)